# Error uploading .sql file on XAMPP

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to upload a .SQL file on XAMPP but I am getting some errors. 
Character set of the file: utf-8
Format: SQL
SQL compatibility mode: NONE

I know I am missing something big. There needs to be some problem right at the beginning. Any help would be appreciated.

**The code is as given below.**

```
USE [CEO3010]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ResAndroid]    Script Date: 04/21/2013 13:49:13 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ResAndroid](
    [Enrollment] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [Roll] [varchar](9) NOT NULL,
    [RNO] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [RollID] [varchar](13) NOT NULL,
    [Part] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CAT] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [ClassSID] [varchar](7) NULL,
    [ClassName] [nvarchar](113) NULL,
    [ExamID] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [ExamName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ClassResult] [varchar](200) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ResAndroid] ([Enrollment], [Roll], [RNO], [RollID], [Part], [CAT], [FirstName], [LastName], [ClassSID], [ClassName], [ExamID], [ExamName], [ClassResult]) VALUES (N'07-4260', N'09MBI012', N'09MSCBI012', N'O1209MBI0121', N'1', 3, N'KAFIL', N'AHMAD', N'11MBI01', N'Master of Science in Bioinformatics Semester - 1', N'O12', N'Semester Examination Dec 2012', N'FAILED IN MBI106 (MB1.6)-[TM UEP IAP]; MBI107 (MB1.7)-[TM UEP IAP];  ')
INSERT [dbo].[ResAndroid] ([Enrollment], [Roll], [RNO], [RollID], [Part], [CAT], [FirstName], [LastName], [ClassSID], [ClassName], [ExamID], [ExamName], [ClassResult]) VALUES (N'07-4260', N'09MBI012', N'09MSCBI012', N'O1209MBI0121', N'1', 3, N'KAFIL', N'AHMAD', N'11MBI01', N'Master of Science in Bioinformatics Semester - 1', N'O12', N'Semester Examination Dec 2012', N'FAILED IN MBI106 (MB1.6)-[TM UEP IAP]; MBI107 (MB1.7)-[TM UEP IAP];  ')
INSERT [dbo].[ResAndroid] ([Enrollment], [Roll], [RNO], [RollID], [Part], [CAT], [FirstName], [LastName], [ClassSID], [ClassName], [ExamID], [ExamName], [ClassResult]) VALUES (N'07-4260', N'09MBI012', N'09MSCBI012', N'O1209MBI0121', N'1', 3, N'KAFIL', N'AHMAD', N'11MBI01', N'Master of Science in Bioinformatics Semester - 1', N'O12', N'Semester Examination Dec 2012', N'FAILED IN MBI106 (MB1.6)-[TM UEP IAP]; MBI107 (MB1.7)-[TM UEP IAP];  ')
and so on.........................
```

Comment: This script is for SQL Server. It won't fly with MySql.

Comment: Oh! I get it. Is there any way to use SQL in XAMPP?

Comment: One of the options is to use php + [PDO_SQLSRV](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php). On the other hand you can always rewrite your db script for MySql.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a MySQL-compatible .sql script.